# pyspark, udf crashing while parsing timestamp value

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a dataframe that i've read from parquet with a value like this

```
+-----------------------+
|date_col               |
+-----------------------+
|20000-01-03 00:00:000.0|
+-----------------------+

root
 |-- date_col: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

I'm trying to filter out improperly formatted dates into a sepperate dataframe, so I run it though this function

```
def time_column_validation(df, col_name, df_err):
    date_verification_udf = udf(date_verification, BooleanType())
    df1 = df.filter(df[col_name].isNotNull()).filter(date_verification_udf(df[col_name]))
    df2 = df1.withColumn('Error_desc', lit('Not date type'))
    df_err = df2.union(df_err)

    return df_err


def date_verification(date_col):
    try:
        if isinstance(date_col, datetime.datetime):
            return False
        else:
            parse(date_col)
            return False
    except:
        return True


err_df = time_column_validation(df, 'date_col', err_df)
err_df.show()
```

df is my datafame shown above,  err_df is just a empty dataframe with the same schema. like this

```
+--------+
|date_col|
+--------+
+--------+
```

but it will fail on err_df.show().  I think the relevant error is this

```
 File "C:\spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\sql\types.py", line 199, in fromInternal
    return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts // 1000000).replace(microsecond=ts % 1000000)
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Somehow it can't handle that date, but i'm not sure where this is happening or why, the date exists in the parquet file and the initial dataframe just fine.  Looking for an explanation and or a suggestion on how to handle a value like this.

I don't care if this particular date get filtered or not, I just don't want the code to crash.

Comment: running the code on a cluster I was able to get this error:   ``` File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1579873218727_0002/container_1579873218727_0002_01_000021/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 199, in fromInternal
    return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts // 1000000).replace(microsecond=ts % 1000000)
ValueError: year 20000 is out of range```

Comment: Just in case anyone comes across this I was never able to solve the issue.  My workaround was to rewrite my udf function so that it did not use datetime.datetime

Comment: Can you share how you did this? I can't do diddly with a Timestamp in a UDF.

Answer (score 0):

here is my workaround:

```
def time_column_validation(df, col_name, df_err):
    date_verification_udf = udf(date_verification, BooleanType())
    df = df.withColumn('new_col', col(col_name).cast(StringType()))
    df1 = df.filter(df[col_name].isNotNull()).filter(date_verification_udf(df['new_col']))
    df2 = df1.drop(col('new_col'))
    df3 = df2.withColumn('Error_desc', lit('Not date type'))
    df_err = df3.union(df_err)

    return df_err

def date_verification(date_col):
    if len(date_col.split(" ")[0]) == 10:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```